# Password field required validation if password field blank but confirm password not blank in symfony

Tags: symfony5

I am very very very new symfony. I am stuck in password and confirm password validation.

I have 2 password field one is password and second is confirm password. When password field is blank and confirm password will not blank after submitting validation message will appear "password field is not blank" instead of "confirm password not match"

I tried:

`$builder ->add(static::FIELD_NEW_PASSWORD, RepeatedType::class, [ 'invalid_message' => static::MESSAGE_PASSWORDS_NOT_MATCHING, 'first_options' => [ 'label' => static::LABEL_NEW_PASSWORD, 'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'off'], ], 'second_options' => [ 'label' => static::LABEL_NEW_PASSWORD_REPEAT, 'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'off'], ], 'required' => true, 'type' => PasswordType::class, 'constraints' => [ new NotBlank(), ], ]);`

Comment: "I need when my password field blank but confirm password will not blank." - what does that mean?

Comment: Meam I have 2 password field one is password and second is confirm password. When password field is blank and confirm password will not blank after submitting validation message will appear "password field is not blank" instead of "confirm password not match"

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Update my question